# How would you solve this polynomial?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Is there a way to find the roots of equations such as $x^3-9\sqrt[3]{2}+9=0$?

I've just been using Wolfram Alpha to factor it into $(x-\sqrt[3]{4}+\sqrt[3]{2}-1)(x^2+(1-\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4})x+3\sqrt[3]{4}-3)$. But for harder equations such as $$x^3-63\sqrt[3]{20}+9=0$$, Wolfram Alpha just factors it into $$(x-\text{root of }x^9+27x^6+243x^3-5000211)(x-\text{same thing})(x-\text{same thing})$$
Which is kind of problematic, because I would like the exact values of the factors.

So is there a way to factor such polynomials into multiple factors? Or some way to find its roots! Anything helps.

---

**Note:** I would not like nested radicals such as $x=\sqrt[3]{3-\sqrt[4]{4}}$ because I then have to go through the process of finding there simplified surds.

Comment: is an $x$ missing?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, I need to find $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find $\sqrt[3]{9(\sqrt[3]2-1)}$ by the following way without WA.

Indeed, let $\sqrt[3]2=x$.

Hence, $$x^3=2$$ or $$9(x^3-1)=9$$ or $$9(x-1)=\frac{9}{1+x+x^2}$$ or $$9(x-1)=\frac{27}{x^3+3x^2+3x+1}$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{9(\sqrt[3]2-1)}=\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]2+1}$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{9(\sqrt[3]2-1)}=\sqrt[3]4-\sqrt[3]2+1$$
and we are done!

Comment: Why did you start off with $x^3=2$? And how did you get from $$9(x-1)=\frac 9{1+x+x^2}$$to$$9(x-1)=\frac {27}{x^3+3x^2+3x+1}$$

Comment: @Frank Because it's comfortable. $\frac{9}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{27}{3+3x+3x^2}=\frac{27}{1+x^3+3x+3x^2}$

Comment: Wait, we have$$\frac {27}{3+3x+3x^2}=\frac {27}{1+x^3+3x+3x^2}$$So how would we work on the other one? I let $x=7\sqrt[3]{20}$ and along the way, I get $9(x^3-1)=6859\implies 9(x-1)=\frac {6859}{x^2+x+1}$. Now, I'm not sure what to do

Answer (score 2):

Say we have the polynomial
$$x^3-(a\sqrt[3]b+c)=0$$
This is going to have one real root:
$$x=\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt[3]b+c}$$
But you said you do not want nested radicals. Then we have the question of whether we can *denest* the radical.

For your first example with $x=\sqrt[3]{9\sqrt[3]2-9}$, you got lucky; the decomposition you gave was shown by Ramanujan. For your second example with $x=\sqrt[3]{63\sqrt[3]{20}-9}$, however, there is no solution with rational numbers and non-nested radicals only. There is an algorithm to determine whether or not the denesting can be done, and [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875230/denesting-ramanujan-radicals) has more on it (in general, it can't be done).

If a denesting does exist, the entire polynomial can be factored into expressions not involving nested radicals. If it doesn't exist, the nested radical provides the *only* exact solution; you could numerically compute $\sqrt[3]{a\sqrt[3]b+c}$ but it isn't going to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove that $\sqrt[3]{63\sqrt[3]{20}-9}=\sqrt[3]{100}+\sqrt[3]{16}-\sqrt[3]5$

See here my generalization: [Denesting radicals like $\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{2} - 1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871639/denesting-radicals-like-sqrt3-sqrt32-1)